# How to yield results from page.on('response') in Playwright?

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to yield the results from a page.on() response function.

I'm using Playwright with Scrapy in Python.

This is how the code looks like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url,
        meta={
            "playwright_page_event_handlers": {
                "response": "check_json",
            },
            'playwright': True,
            "playwright_include_page": True})

async def parse(self, response):
    # initiate page instance
    page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

    # get response
    page.on("response", self.check_json)

    # scroll page
    n_scrolls = 10
    for i in range(n_scrolls):
        await page.mouse.wheel(0, 15000)
        logger.info('scrolling...')
        time.sleep(2)
        await page.mouse.wheel(0, -1500)
        logger.info('move up')

    await page.close()
    
async def check_json(self, response):
""" this function is started with the method "on" from playwright """

    if 'something' in response.url:

        items= await response.json()
        item1 = items['an_item']

        yield item1
```

If I print item1 I see the output, but when I yield nothing happens.