# Python & Playwright page.on("response", lambda........) struggling to understand and getting compounding result

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have used playwright literature and followed John Watson Rooney tutorial (Thank you John).[Is THIS the Best Way to Scrape Data with Playwright?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUOl4W_3tTg) My issue is a compounding response. I would like a single call made for a, b ,c. The result I currently have is a,b,b,c,c,c or worse.

I have the following code:

```
search_list = ['a','b','c']

def test_json(response, results):
    try:
        results.append(
            {
                'url': response.url,
                'data': response.json(),
            }
        )
        print(response.json())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"How exceptional! {e}")

def run(playwright, search_list):
    results = []
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    for value in search_list:
        # inputs value into page
        page.fill(value_no, value)
        # sends request
        page.click(search_button)
        # Waits for page to load
        page.is_visible("form.form-group")
        # Not sure how this part works?
        page.on("response", lambda response: test_json(response, results))
        # Put this in as it "seemed" shut down the window before grabbing json?
        page.click(material_pricing_tab)
    return results

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    data = run(playwright, search_list)
    with open ('results.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(data,f)`
```

Also tried to understand the following post:
([How to yield results from page.on('response') in Playwright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77467339/how-to-yield-results-from-page-onresponse-in-playwright))
Even tried CHATGTP....
I am struggling with the lambda function and am thinking that the "response" is compounding the request.

I have tried taking the results "list" out of the lambda formula but it makes little difference to the result, if fact I get even more data in my file.

If I remove the for loop I get close to what I need, there is "pre" .json and then the .json file I want. Side note if I could filter out the "pre" .json that would be good but not the answer to my question. My issue is on the first time around the loop it works successfully. When it iterates to the next value I get two versions of that value (only one of the first) and when it goes through the loop for the third time I get three versions of the that value and so on. ie [a,b,b,c,c,c]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am learning Python but started to use playwright. I am struggling to understand the lambda function and sure that is my issue.

Thank you

Comment: `page.on` only needs to be called once, generally. You're setting up a new listener each time through the loop. It's asynchronous code that runs the lambda whenever a response arrives, not synchronous code that waits for a response to fire. Call it once before the loop. A [mcve] would be good, with the page you're working with, or a simple reproduction of it that's relevant to the problem. Without that, it's pretty hard to write an answer that I can actually verify. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen your explanation was brilliant thank you - clearer than my question. The website I needed to remove references. I thought I left enough there (my ignorance). You have answered my question I not sure how to give thumbs up? Thank you!

Comment: You may also want [`page.expect_response`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response) which is an inline version of `page.on`.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen really appreciate your advise. I am very green but reading the literature I think it is exactly what I need, a bit of practice....... Thank you.